# Wikipedia url, is english language code needed for interwiki linking between 2 languages?

Tags: url, mediawiki, wikipedia, wiki

I don't know where to ask this (suggestions appreciated.) (I checked Stackexchange but there is no "stack-wiki" forum & I can't find any other place either to ask, only wiki-help articles that is not about my problem)

**Background:**

I have just created this wiki (the whole wiki, not just the article)

https://finalupgrade.fandom.com/wiki/Final_Upgrade_Wiki

And I want to add a [interwiki](https://community.fandom.com/wiki/Help:Interlanguage_link) link to the Russian version: (created by another user)

https://final-upgrade.fandom.com/ru/wiki/Final_Upgrade_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8

**Question:**

I noticed that the Russian version has a `/ru` in the url, but my English version does not have a `/en`, **Is that a problem?**

Or does the English version get a `/en` when we link the sites?

Or is it simply not needed? (for some reason?)

Comment: `where to ask this` - arguably, at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Will use that next time then.